# Kendo server export POST request headers

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo's server side export functionality to be able to export xlsx/pdfs from the server. This is my configuration

```
kendo.saveAs({
  dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
  fileName: "STRResult.xlsx",
  proxyURL:'/my/kendo/export/kendoServerExport',
  forceProxy:true,
  proxyTarget: "_blank"
});
```

The problem here is that I have a server (without code access) in Spring MCV and it has a global filter that checks for certain headers. I want to be able to set the required headers on this post request.

What configuration do I need to use to get it working?

TIA

Comment: The files are a part of post request data. Which is always handled as form data but with form enctype="multipart/form-data" on html side. So just put that header in your kendo request and send it.

Comment: @HimeshSuthar : How do I add request headers that is the question. As far as what's there is documentation, the `.saveAs` function builds a post request. I am not sure if the function that actually sends the request is exposed to the user.

Comment: I am not able to send request using above method.It is giving t.split is not a function error.Can you tell why?

Answer (score -1):

I've provided a solution for this on the Kendo UI forum.
You can find it [HERE](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-xhr-request-headers-with-kendo-saveas())

Solution as described on the forum:

I've build a solution for this based on some info found elsewhere on the internet.

I would like to share it with you, so perhaps Telerik might want to use is in some future version ;)

```
//#region -- Download file and save data to a local file --
    // Invoke call to webservice and save file
    // url - Url to get the file from
    // method - GET/POST method
    // defaultFilename - Default filename if none was given from the server
    , saveAs: function (url, method, defaultFilename)
    {
        var caller = this;

        Insad.ajaxMaskUI({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': Insad.GetBaseAuthenticationToken()
                // ... Put your headers in here ...
            },
            maskUI: Insad.defaultMaskUI
            , maskPageMsg: 'Downloading file'
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //console.log('error:', textStatus, errorThrown, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(), xhr);
            var msg = xhr.responseText;
            if (msg === undefined) {
                msg = 'Unknown error';
            }
            console.log('FileDownload failed -> Error handler. Errormessage: ', msg);
            ShowWarning(msg);

            caller.handleUIErrorDownload();
        })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            caller.handleUISuccessDownload(xhr, defaultFilename);
        });
    }
    , handleUIErrorDownload: function ()
    {
        console.log('handleUIError');
        // TODO: Reset stuff / give user more info?
        // ... Put your code in here ...
    }
    , handleUISuccessDownload: function (xhr, defaultFilename)
    {
        console.log('handleUISuccess');

        // Save file
        var filename = Insad.GetFilenameFromContent(xhr);
        if (filename === '') {
            filename = defaultFilename;
        }
        Insad.SaveDataToFile(filename, xhr.responseText, xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));

        // TODO: Give user more info?
        // ... Put your code in here ...
    }
//#endregion

//#region -- Save data to a local file --
    // Get the filename from the Content-Disposition in the response xhr
    , GetFilenameFromContent: function (xhr)
    {
        var filename = '';
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        // Only when inline or attachment are supported at this moment
        if (disposition && (disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1 || disposition.indexOf('inline') !== -1)) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
                filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }
        }
        return filename;
    }

    // The function that will write the data to a file :)
    , SaveDataToFile: function (filename, data, mimeType)
    {
        var dataFileAsBlob = new Blob([data], {type:mimeType});
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download";
        if (window.webkitURL !== null) {                        // Is it Chrome based?
            // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
            // without actually adding it to the DOM.
            downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(dataFileAsBlob);
        }
        else {
            // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
            // before it can be clicked.
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(dataFileAsBlob);
            downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;       // --> TODO: ?? TEST ?? On Opera use: downloadLink.onclick = document.body.removeChild(event.target);
            downloadLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        }
        // Force download
        downloadLink.click();
    }
//#endregion
```

This is a part from our base library (Insad).

I think you get the idea. If you're missing something I would be happy to provide it to you :)

Instead of calling the 'old' saveAs like:

```
kendo.saveAs({
    dataURI: url,
    fileName: defaultFilename,
    forceProxy: false
});
```

You can now use:

```
Insad.saveAs({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',  // or use 'POST' if you really must ;)
    defaultFilename: defaultFilename
});
```

I left out the animation part but that shouldn't be to hard I think :)